# GTK2 applications are not themed correctly

Tags: themes, gtk-2

On my Ubuntu 13.04 machine suddenly all GTK2 applications (like Firefox, LibreOffice etc.) are not themed anymore (I am using Ubuntu's Standard theme). Instead, they are shown with this ugly old default theme. 
I didn't do anything that could have caused that behaviour, as far as I know. 
Does anybody know what to do?

UPDATE: Maybe a system crash (I had before), that forced me to do a cold reboot, has damaged some system configurations files. But I don't have an idea which one, or how to check.

[image]

The screenshot shows the problem: Gedit is themed and Firefox is not. It occurs only when I log in with my user account. With any other everything is ok.

Comment: Firefox and LibreOffice are, to a significant extent, gtk2 apps.

Comment: @vasa1 Ah, did not know that. Chromium as well? My be it is about GTK2 Apps.

Comment: @vasa1 I edited my question.

Comment: Yes, Chromium/Chrome as well. As far as I know, Ambiance/Radiance are the "standard" Ubuntu themes and both support gtk2 apps as well as gtk3 apps. Could you mention the exact name and source of the theme you currently are using? If you look in the theme's folder, you _should_ see subfolders for both gtk-2.0 and gtk-3.0.

Comment: Did you by chance edit the theme's gtkrc or ~/.gtkrc-2.0? It's possible that wrong syntax can cause a problem.

Comment: And the "ugly" minimal look maybe because apps are being themed with Raleigh which I think is the "fallback" theme when the selected theme breaks somehow.

Comment: @vasa I am using Ambiance, the standard theme, and never changed anything. Not for the current user, nor for the system. Regarding the ugly look, I think, you are right. May be the problem is caused by an system crash I had before. I had to do a cold restart. Thank you, for your help!

Comment: If a restart fixed your problem, you could mention that an answer. It maybe helpful to others :)

Comment: I have the same problem after installing kde and then going back to gnome.

Comment: The only thing that helped me was to deleted the folder ~/.config/dconf But this will delete many settings you may have mad as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem after installing kde and then going back to gnome. I managed to *mostly* fix it by editing `~/.gtkrc-2.0`. It had references to `oxygen` theme in it which is the kde theme I guess. So I changed those to `Ambiance` and `ubuntu-mono-dark`. No guarantee this will fix it for you though.

```
style "user-font" 
{
    font_name="Ubuntu Regular"
}
widget_class "*" style "user-font"
gtk-font-name="Ubuntu Regular 8"
gtk-theme-name="Ambiance"
gtk-icon-theme-name="ubuntu-mono-dark"
gtk-fallback-icon-theme="gnome"
gtk-toolbar-style=GTK_TOOLBAR_ICONS
gtk-menu-images=1
gtk-button-images=1
```

Comment: I LOVE YOU SO MUCH I HAD TO USE CAPS LOCK TO TELL YOU THIS!!! I thought my system is broken forever...