# How to get rid of toolbar text?

Tags: gtk3

How to get rid of the text that appears at the bottom of all toolbar icons? It suddenly has shown up after a system crash although I didn't change anything and now I can't make it disappear:

[image]

I tried to set the following setting with dconf-editor:

```
org.gnome.desktop.interface toolbar-style
```

to the value ›text‹ and logged out and in, but didn't help at all. What to do?

UPDATE: The setting in gconf is correct as shown by the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: if you run the command: gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface toolbar-style icons . to only have icons?

Comment: @RomanRaguet I tried that as well, but didn't work neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following command in terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface toolbar-style 'icons'
```

The other valid values are: `'both'`, `'both-horiz'`, and `'text'`.

The changes should be visible immediately, so you don't need any restart or re-login.

Comment: I already tried that (look at the comments of the original post) but didn't work out.

Comment: @user5950 Have you tried exactly as I wrote?

Comment: Yes, I did it twice with copy and past. And I checked the value of that setting with gconf-editor. It is set to 'icons'. But the text is shown anyway. Very strange!

Comment: @user5950 Then you have a bug because this is the right way. See [http://askubuntu.com/q/5121/147044](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug). Do you use any others configuration/tweak tools like dconf?

Comment: Yes, dconf is installed: should I remove it? Isn't it installed by default?

Comment: @user5950 No, don't remove it! I asked if you use other apps like it.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this problem occurs when the Cinnamon ppa ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable is used. It is related with:

[Nemo 2.0 does not render desktop correctly with Compiz](https://askubuntu.com/questions/358584/nemo-2-0-does-not-render-desktop-correctly-with-compiz)

[GTK2 applications are not themed correctly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/322270)

Purging the ppa resolves all of those tree problems:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable
```