# Hide text for Kate toolbar butons

Tags: gnome, icons, kate

I am under Ubuntu 20.04.2, using kate 19.12.3.
My toolbar looks like this

[image]

**Is there any way to hide the text next to each icon in the toolbar?**

Ideally, they would show as a tooltip, as in many other applications (at least in Windows... not that I am a fan of Win but in this the UI seems better). But otherwise, just show the icons.

I already used `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface toolbar-style 'icons'` ([source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359039/how-to-get-rid-of-toolbar-text)), and it doesn't work (I didn't expect it to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to:

1. launch Kate
2. right mouse click on the *Toolbar*
3. from *Text Position* select *Icons Only*

Comparison is below:

| **Text Position → Text Alongside Icons** | **Text Position → Icons Only** |
| --- | --- |
| [image: with text] | [image: without text] |

---

Note: Kate is the Qt-based application, so it is not controlled by `gsettings` / `dconf`.

Comment: Perfect! And with tooltips, so I take back my comparison with Windows.
I searched the web, and I did not find this, I wonder how that happened.
I know about Kate-Qt, that is why I said "I didn't expect it to".